# Invoke pre-parsed command line with Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, security, command-line, exec

I need to invoke the following command, where password is user input. However, I am worried about the possibility of an attack, such as `"; rm -rf / ;"` being the input given by the user.

```
var checkPassword = exec('echo "'+password+ '"| cracklib-check\n', function(err, stdout, stderr) {
...
...
}
```

is there a way to invoke the command with pre-parsed arguments (preferably native to nodejs/ javascript), kind of like prepared statements which are used to avoid SQL injection?

I could probably avoid the problem by blacklisting certain characters, but that seems much less reliable, and I'd like to avoid it is possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@Ilmora's answered me started, but I still had to handle encoding.

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

// Read password from argument to nodejs invocation
var password = process.argv[2];

var cracklib_check = spawn('/usr/sbin/cracklib-check');

cracklib_check.stdin.setEncoding = 'utf-8';
cracklib_check.stdin.write(password);
cracklib_check.stdin.end();

// Process results of cracklib-check
cracklib_check.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log("[*] " + data.toString());
});

cracklib_check.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log("[-] " + data.toString());
});
```

Answer (score 1):

As you point out, building a command line with user provided input is a security issue. Typically you would write a wrapper that verifies that each user-provided parameter meets a white-list before invoking the command.

In your case however there is a simpler solution: you are constructing a command line that simply sends the password to the stdin of `cracklib-check`. Instead of using `child_process.exec` you can switch to `child_process.spawn` which allows you to write directly to stdin, avoiding the need to build a command line with user-provided input.

The following sample code avoids the security problem:

```
const spawn = require('child_process').spawn;

// Read password from argument to nodejs invocation
var password = process.argv[2];

// Spawn cracklib-check
var cracklib_check = spawn("/usr/sbin/cracklib-check");

// Send password to cracklib-check STDIN
cracklib_check.stdin.write(password);
cracklib_check.stdin.end();

// Process results of cracklib-check
cracklib_check.stdout.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log("[*] " + data);
});

cracklib_check.stderr.on('data', function (data) {
  console.log("[-] " + data);
});
```

Comment: Seems like this might work, haven'thad time to implement it yet though.